# When did the practice of having a joke with no music at the end of a trailer begin?

Tags: trailers

Many modern day trailers, especially for action-y movies follow a very similar format.

1. Short and relatively slow paced intro of the major player and plot. Music is slow to match
2. Real action start. Music picks up, lots of short climatic shots. This is where the movie gets really sold
3. **Music cuts out. Video goes from lots of short cuts to a single, slow paces scene, often times of a joke. This will last maybe 15 seconds or so.**
4. Music returns again in a slow form. Outro credits and movie title is shown.

A good example is the Suicide Squad trailer

When did this format of trailers begin (specifically step 3)? It seems like every trailer I see nowadays does the exact same thing.

Edit: more examples as requested:

Two new trailers, Pirates of the Caribbean and Justice League. THey both do this.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific genre? Because trailers tend to vary on a number of things. I am sure this trailer you'av just shared is gigantically different from films like. Her (2013), The Lobster (2015), Blindness (2008)

Comment: @SudipBiswas I mention in the first sentence of my question that this is mainly for action movies. Also why the downvote (@whoever)?

Comment: I was not the one who down voted your question. I simply added comment because I was not sure if this was only regarding action movies as you said "especially"? I always make it a point to add a comment for a down vote, but this unknown person doesn't seem to have that habit.

Comment: @SudipBiswas Yeah, thats why I added the @ whoever

Comment: Also, for whoever is saying this is too broad - I'm asking a very specific question - when did this start

Comment: You cite one example. If this practice is so widespread as you claim -- "every trailer I see nowadays" -- then you should be able to provide dozens of such examples and not one that's a year and a half old.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Posted a few more that took less than 5 minutes of searching

Comment: Two of the four additional ones are years old, the two most recent ones date back to December 2015. Considering the volume of action movies and considering you claim this phenomenon applies to "every trailer I see nowadays", you should easily be able to provide us with a substantial list of *recently* released trailers. Also, the Tron trailer doesn't even have a joke at the end, and you don't even mention the joke in your four-step formula.

Comment: @BCdotWEB this is a question, not a book report. I'm not going to list out every single trailer sorted by date. I really don't understand what you're looking for. I've shown a clear pattern an an asking when it started. I'll edit my question to fix step 3 (my bad).

Comment: You claim to perceive a trend in "many modern day trailers" and even "every trailer I see nowadays", and yet you cannot offer any recent evidence and can only provide a few anecdotal ones, most from years ago. As I've pointed out before, if your claim was true then you should have no problem listing *dozens* of *recent* trailers. Considering the volume of movies and especially trailers, five examples -- one of them from 2011(!) -- isn't a trend.

Comment: "Seems like every..." is a common expression which is used as hyperbole. He's not claiming that literally every trailer uses it. His examples are just to help us understand what practice he's talking about; he's not out to prove that all trailers use it. Seems like a reasonable question to me; when did trailers start doing this.

Comment: Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 2 does this too: https://youtu.be/rEpsPXUt4R0

Comment: @GendoIkari Yep, lots of movies do this. I bet Vol 1 did it too. The question is, when did it start? o.O?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Like I said... I am not going to list out every trailer that does it here because this isn't a research paper. That's just silly and having a full list isn't really relevant. I've shown that this pattern dates back years at least, and another commenter just posted above of _another_ trailer that does this. There are many many more out there. I'm not going to list them all. Also I don't know why you're asking for recent trailers - my question is about the past not about the now. Though I suppose gendolkari's comment meets your "recent" criteria for whatever its worth.